# How to upload file from nested form & prevent client validation of master form in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, validation, file-upload

When I click on nested forms submit button to upload file, it fires client validation and I want to prevent this.
I have tried with two separate form element and it works. But I have to use nested form element as this is requirement(For design purpose).

Below is my code.

**View code**

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddEdit", "Leads", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "frmSaveLead", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
     {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.stTitle, new { @class = "m-wrap span12",     @placeholder = "Lead Title", @maxlength = "100" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.stTitle)

        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.stNote, new { @class = "m-wrap span12", @placeholder = "Lead Note" })

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.stNote)

        @using (Html.BeginForm("FileUpload", "Leads", FormMethod.Post, new { @Id = "frmFileUpload", @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {

             <span class="btn green fileinput-button"><i class="icon-plus icon-white">              </i>
             <span>Add file...</span>
             <input type="file" name="files">
             </span>

             <button type="submit" class="btn blue start">
                     <i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i><span>Start upload</span>
             </button>
        }

        <button type="submit" class="btn blue">
            <i class="icon-ok"></i>Save
       </button>
    }
```

Comment: "I have to use nested form element as this is requirement" That's a horrible requirement seeing how nested forms are not allowed as per HTML spec.

Comment: @Marek, yes I know, it is not proper way. But for design purpose.

Comment: you can try sending form as json using jquery

Comment: @Nilesh, But how I can send HttpPostedFileBase object to my controller's ActionResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner form

```
<form id="login-form">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="files" accept="image/*;capture=camera">
    <button type="button" onclick="submitform()">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Jquery

```
function submitform(){
        var postdata = $('#login-form').serialize();          
        var file = document.getElementById('files').files[0];
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("files", file);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/Home/Index", false);
        xhr.send(fd);    
    }
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Index(FormCollection data)
    {

      if (Request.Files["files"] != null)
        {
           HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files["files"];
        }
        return Json(something);
    }
```

Comment: Is Imagefile is equivalent to type of HttpPostedFileBase ?

Comment: Yes it is equivalent to type of HttpPostedFileBase

Comment: Okay, I will try this. See you later. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, Request.Files["files"] is equivalent to HttpPostedFileBase's object.

Comment: And why we need to append, fd.append("files", file); ? Please explain me.